# Nivo Slider Image Link doesn't work in IE? what the heck

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index, nivo-slider

I've got the Wordpress Nivo slider installed on this page www.ldf.org The slider image links work in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. I've tried adjusting the z-index on every element that I can think of but no luck. Any suggestions?